# I want to show Monthly Events on Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, rrule

I have a small problem in which i am stuck. I am Using Full Calendar v4.4.0. In my web app the customer can create an event with frequency of (One time, Weekly and Monthly). I have successfully shown event on Full Calendar which occurs one time and weekly. But i am stuck in showing the monthly events.

One more thing the events data is coming from data base so i dont want to push same event which occurs monthly or weekly in database. I just want one instance in it. For weekly purpose i am successfull.

Let me share my code with you

```
  $model = Event::find()->all(); // getting events from database
    foreach ($model as $mod)//looping 
    {
        $day=array(); // for weekly purpose making day array for repeatabel
        if ($mod->event_frequency==2) // checking if the event is weekly
        {
            $start=date('N', strtotime($mod->start_time)); // getting start day
            $end=date('N', strtotime($mod->end_time)); // getting end day
            if($start==$end)
            {
                $day[]=$start;
            }
            else
            {
                $day[]=$start;
                $day[]=$end;
            }
            $data[]=[
                'id' =>$mod->id,
                'title'=>$mod->event_name,
                'start'           => $mod->start_time,
                'end'             => $mod->end_time,
                'backgroundColor' => $mod->event_tag_color,
                'textColor'       => '#FFF', 
                'daysOfWeek' => $day // for repeatable events showing
                
            ];
           
        }
        else if($mod->event_frequency==3) // for monthly
        {
            $start=date('N', strtotime($mod->start_time));
            $end=date('N', strtotime($mod->end_time));
            if($start==$end)
            {
                $day[]=$start;
            }
            else
            {
                $day[]=$start;
                $day[]=$end;
            }
            $data[]=[
                'id' =>$mod->id,
                'title'=>$mod->event_name,
                'start'           => $mod->start_time,
                'end'             => $mod->end_time,
                'backgroundColor' => $mod->event_tag_color,
                'textColor'       => '#FFF', 
           // stuck here for days 
                'rrule'=> [
                        'freq'=> 'MONTHLY',
                        'interval'=> '5',
                        'dtstart'=> $start,
                        'until' => '2022-12-31',
                       ],
                
            ];
        }
        else
        {
        
            $data[]=[
                'id' =>$mod->id,
                'title'=>$mod->event_name,
                'start'           => $mod->start_time,
                'end'             => $mod->end_time,
                'backgroundColor' => $mod->event_tag_color,
                'textColor'       => '#FFF', 
                
            ];
        }
```

Kindly help please

Thanks a bundle

EDIT:

I added rrule.min.js and tried to send the rrule via json but its not showing on calender. Added the rest of the parameters too.

The complete json is coming as  which is populating the events

```
[
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Testing Event 1",
    "start": "2021-02-24 09:00:00",
    "end": "2021-02-24 18:00:00",
    "backgroundColor": "#F9072C",
    "textColor": "#FFF"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Testing Event 2",
    "start": "2021-02-26 09:00:00",
    "end": "2021-02-26 18:00:00",
    "backgroundColor": "#6453E9",
    "textColor": "#FFF"
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "title": "Testing Event 3",
    "start": "2021-02-25 09:00:00",
    "end": "2021-02-25 18:00:00",
    "backgroundColor": "#53E984",
    "textColor": "#FFF"
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "title": "Testing Event 4",
    "start": "2021-02-27 10:00:00",
    "end": "2021-02-27 21:00:00",
    "backgroundColor": "#E9CB53",
    "textColor": "#FFF",
    "rrule": {
        "freq": "MONTHLY",
        "interval": "1",
        "dtstart": "2021-02-27 10:00:00",
        "until": "2022-12-31"
    }
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "title": "Testing Event",
    "start": "2021-03-12 09:00:00",
    "end": "2021-03-12 18:00:00",
    "backgroundColor": "#FF000F",
    "textColor": "#FFF"
},
{
    "id": 11,
    "title": "testing one",
    "start": "2021-03-09 04:45:00",
    "end": "2021-03-10 04:45:00",
    "backgroundColor": "#6453E9",
    "textColor": "#FFF",
    "daysOfWeek": [
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
},
{
    "id": 12,
    "title": "Testing with Monthly",
    "start": "2021-03-23 09:00:00",
    "end": "2021-03-23 17:00:00",
    "backgroundColor": "#025B0E",
    "textColor": "#FFF",
    "rrule": {
        "freq": "MONTHLY",
        "interval": "1",
        "dtstart": "2021-03-23 09:00:00",
        "until": "2022-12-31"
    }
}
```

]

The calendar.js is as follows

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var url ='./';

$('body').on('click', '.datetimepicker', function() {
    $(this).not('.hasDateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
        controlType: 'select',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
        yearRange: "1900:+10",
        showOn:'focus',
        firstDay: 1
    }).focus();
});

$(".colorpicker").colorpicker();

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar-event');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list','rrule'],
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
    },
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    businessHours: true, // display business hours
    editable: true,
    //uncomment to have a default date
    //defaultDate: '2020-04-07',
    events: url+'calender/load', // this is where the events are populating
    
    eventDrop: function(arg) {
        var start = arg.event.start.toDateString()+' '+arg.event.start.getHours()+':'+arg.event.start.getMinutes()+':'+arg.event.start.getSeconds();
        if (arg.event.end == null) {
            end = start;
        } else {
            var end = arg.event.end.toDateString()+' '+arg.event.end.getHours()+':'+arg.event.end.getMinutes()+':'+arg.event.end.getSeconds();
        }

        $.ajax({
          url:url+"calender/update",
          type:"POST",
          data:{id:arg.event.id, start:start, end:end},
        });
    },
    eventResize: function(arg) {
        var start = arg.event.start.toDateString()+' '+arg.event.start.getHours()+':'+arg.event.start.getMinutes()+':'+arg.event.start.getSeconds();
        var end = arg.event.end.toDateString()+' '+arg.event.end.getHours()+':'+arg.event.end.getMinutes()+':'+arg.event.end.getSeconds();

        $.ajax({
          url:url+"calender/update",
          type:"POST",
          data:{id:arg.event.id, start:start, end:end},
        });
    },
    eventClick: function(arg) {
        var id = arg.event.id;
        
        $('#editEventId').val(id);
        $('#deleteEvent').attr('data-id', id); 
        
        $.ajax({
          url:url+"calender/get-event",
          type:"POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          data:{id:id},
          success: function(data) {
            //   debugger;
              
                $('#name').val(data.title);
                $('#start').val(data.start);
                $('#end').val(data.end);
                $('#color').val(data.color);
                $('#comments').val(data.comments);
                $('#venue').val(data.venue);
                $('#frequency').val(data.frequency);
                $('#event_id').val(data.id);
                // $('#editTextColor').val(data.textColor);
                // $('#editeventmodal').modal();
            }
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#deleteEvent', function() {
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:url+"api/delete.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{id:arg.event.id},
                }); 

                //close model
                $('#editeventmodal').modal('hide');

                //refresh calendar
                calendar.refetchEvents();         
            }
        });
        
        calendar.refetchEvents();
    }
});

calendar.render();



$(".ajax_form").on("submit",function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.prop('method'),
        url: $form.prop('action'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        
        success: function (response) {
            //alert(response.status);
           
            if (response.status==="ok"){
                
                calendar.refetchEvents();
                
                $(".ajax_form").trigger("reset");
                

        }
        else 
        {
             
        }
        },
         error: function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert(response.d);
        }

});

});

$(".edit-event-calender").on("click",function(evt) {
    $data=$('form').serialize();
    $url=$(this).data('url');
    
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $url,
            data: $data,
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            
            success: function (response) {
                //alert(response.status);
            
                if (response.status==="ok"){
                    
                    calendar.refetchEvents();
                    
                    $(".ajax_form").trigger("reset");
                    

            }
            else 
            {
                
            }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                debugger;
                alert(response.d);
            }

    });
});

$(".delete-event-calender").on("click",function(evt) {
    $data=$('form').serialize();
    $url=$(this).data('url');
    
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $url,
            data: $data,
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            
            success: function (response) {
                //alert(response.status);
            
                if (response.status==="ok"){
                    
                    calendar.refetchEvents();
                    
                    $(".ajax_form").trigger("reset");
                    

            }
            else 
            {
                
            }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                debugger;
                alert(response.d);
            }

    });
});
```

});

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/rrule-plugin

Comment: tried to implement but its not working. Let me update the code for you as well

Comment: I think you need to specify more than just that in the rrule. Look at the examples

Comment: still the same no affect.

Comment: updated the code for you as well @ADyson

Comment: dtstart is supposed to be a date according to the examples and documentation

Comment: updated it again. But still cant see

Comment: And you probably need to remove start and end of the main fullCalendar event, and just do all the config within the rrule

Comment: `{
"6":` shouldn't be part of any JSON you pass to fullCalendar. You should be passing an array of event objects

Comment: P.s. Did you also add the rrule library and fullCalendar rrule plugin to your page as well?

Comment: i have added it through script

Comment: no the { "6":  is the event object which occurs monthly. there are multiple events which are populating the calender

Comment: Ok but that's not a valid format for fullCalendar. You need to supply an **array**, not an object. And you need to adjust the "interval" variable correctly, and as a number not a string. Here's a simple working example: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/NWdPNxw

Comment: your example is working but when i try to implement it its not working. 

I am getting events from server and is sending them via json may be there is an issue in json which is not implementing the rrule ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230264/discussion-between-kool-coder-and-adyson).

Comment: added the complete code as well

Comment: Interval needs to be a number not a string, as I mentioned Get rid of the quote marks round it. Notice it doesn't have any in my example, or in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much worked... the mistake was interval. It needs to be integer rather than string

Comment: No problem. Remember that small details and differences are often significant in programming